# Populating a list is Scala with random double taking forever

Tags: performance, list, scala

I am new to Scala and am trying to get a list of random double values:

The thing is, when I try to run this, it takes way too long compared to its Java counterpart.  Any ideas on why this is or a suggestion on a more efficient approach?

```
def random: Double = java.lang.Math.random()
var f = List(0.0)
for (i <- 1 to 200000)
 ( f = f ::: List(random*100)) 
 f = f.tail
```

Comment: By using ::: in this fashion, you're rebuilding the entire list with each iteration. Ideally, you'd actually be using a lazy data structure, but if you really want a list use `f = (random * 100) :: f`

Comment: Also, start with `var f: List[Double] = Nil` - and there's no need to def random, just import it: `import java.lang.Math.random`

Comment: BTW, `java.lang.Math.random()` is not especially random (see: [http://alife.co.uk/nonrandom/](http://alife.co.uk/nonrandom/)). A good alternative (there are others) is [http://www.cs.gmu.edu/~sean/research/mersenne/MersenneTwisterFast.java](http://www.cs.gmu.edu/~sean/research/mersenne/MersenneTwisterFast.java).

Comment: There's also a `scala.util.Random`, no need to use the Java version.

Comment: @Jesper : Right. But it should still be noted that `scala.util.Random` is just a wrapper for `java.util.Random()`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can also achieve it like this:

```
List.fill(200000)(math.random)
```

the same goes for e.g. Array ...

```
Array.fill(200000)(math.random)
```

etc ...

Comment: That's the Scalarific way to do it, "Scalarific" being the word I have coined to mean "conforming to the commonly-accepted Scala idiom", in parallel with "Pythonic" -- nominations for any alternative words gladly accepted.

Comment: @Malvolio: how about "Scalar?" :)

Comment: @Malvolio: I nominate "Scalacious"

Answer (score 9):

You could construct an infinite stream of random doubles:

```
def randomList(): Stream[Double] = Stream.cons(math.random, randomList)

val f = randomList().take(200000)
```

This will leverage lazy evaluation so you won't calculate a value until you actually need it.  Even evaluating all 200,000 will be fast though.  As an added bonus, `f` no longer needs to be a `var`.

Comment: Thanks Mr Byrne, any ideas as to why my dying so badly?  I think it is because of the ::: resulting in generating a new list each time and as such being a killer on the cpu?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  You are rebuilding the entire list each iteration.

Answer (score 7):

Another possibility is:

```
val it = Iterator.continually(math.random)
it.take(200000).toList
```

`Stream` also has a `continually` method if you prefer.

Comment: Use `math.random` and it's the answer I would have given :)

Comment: @Kevin: Of course. Changed. My excuse is that I usually use a [Mersenne Twister](http://www.cs.gmu.edu/~sean/research/mersenne/MersenneTwisterFast.java) instead, anyway...

Answer (score 5):

First of all, it is not taking longer than java because there is no java counterpart. Java does not have an immutable list. If it did, performance would be about the same.

Second, its taking a lot of time because appending lists have linear performance, so the whole thing has quadratic performance.

Instead of appending, prepend, which had constant performance.

Answer (score 4):

if your using mutable state anyways you should use a mutable collection like buffer which you can add too with `+=` (which then would be the *real* counterpart to java code).

but why dont u use list comprehension?

```
val f = for (_ <- 1 to 200000) yield (math.random * 100)
```

---

by the way: `var f = List(0.0)` ... `f = f.tail` can be replaced by `var f: List[Double] = Nil` in your example. (no more performance but more beauty ;)

Comment: One minor adjustment: val f = for (_ <- 1 to 200000) yield (math.random * 100)

Comment: Thanks Martin, very succint and clean alternative.

Comment: Hey thanks Martin, but I notice something about that alternative - If I attempt to pass that list to an actor it takes forever (over a list of 20 doubles) - but my original code does not over a list of size 20.

Answer (score 2):

Yet more options!  Tail recursion:

```
def randlist(n: Int, part: List[Double] = Nil): List[Double] = {
  if (n<=0) part
  else randlist(n-1, 100*random :: part)
}
```

or mapped ranges:

```
(1 to 200000).map(_ => 100*random).toList
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want to use Vector instead of List. List has O(1) prepend, Vector has O(1) append. Since you are appending, but using concatenation, it'll be faster to use Vector:

```
def random: Double = java.lang.Math.random()
var f: Vector[Double] = Vector()
for (i <- 1 to 200000)
  f = f :+ (random*100)
```

Got it?

Comment: Does it really matter if your random numbers come out backwards?

Comment: Thanks for this.  The sequence does not matter (in my instance) as they will all be passed to actors for selection sort anyway.